# How to check that Column's 1 text is present in column's 2 text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am very new to excel. I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns. For an example consider the following :

[image]

Now, I need to write a formula in excel, that will return true if column two (**Process Full Path**) has the substring present in column 1 (**Process Name**) or it will return false. As an example, for the given data both the result will be true.

**Row 1:** Column 1's data `svchost.exe` is present in As Column 2's data `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe` : **Result : TRUE**

**Row 2:** Column 1's data `ShellExperienceHost.exe` is present in As Column 2's data `C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_sdf\ShellExperienceHost.exe` : **Result : TRUE**

Can anybody help me with the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C2`:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2))
```

Drag down.

[image]